# Fixing spikes in an audio file using a CLI tool

Tags: audio-recording

I have an audio file which has (I believe) spikes due to an encoding error. Below is a screenshot from adobe audition.

[image: screenshot from adobe audition]

How do I fix such thing using an command line tool? (CLI is important because I have a couple hundred of these)

Comment: Spikes in an audio file-  Not to be confused with -  Audiophile spikes.